# How to handle file from POST requests in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, aws-lambda, python-requests

I am sending file via requests.post method in python 3.7. The code is something as simple as the following,

```
with open('filename','rb') as data:
    r = requests.post(url, data)
```

The request is sent to a handler created on AWS Lambda, where the file should then be stored in other services. The body of the event seems to be an encoded string of the file object and I can't find a way to decode it.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Well, you opened it in bytes mode with `'rb'`; why?

Comment: I was going to put it in an s3 bucket, which takes in data in bytes or file format; also most examples I found were reading in binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not a great ideia. Lambda has Invocation payload [limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of 6MB, so you can't send large files like this.

The best way is to use `boto3` [appropriate function to upload files directly to S3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)

If you really want to use `requests.post`, open the file as a string and send It via post, something like that:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    STRING_FILE = file.read().replace('\n', '')
    r = requests.post(<URL>, data = {'key':STRING_FILE})
```